# Java - public static void main()

Tags: java

Should there be any specific order in which I should write the following for a Java main method?

`public static void main()`

In other words, can I re-shuffle public, static, void in any order?

Why or why not?

Comment: You're asking a lot of these questions in very rapid succession. I encourage you to read the Java language specification ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html ) which will answer many of these inquiries. Some experimentation with your compiler will also be useful.

Comment: @John Feminella - It is nice to see that someone can recognize that the OP has asked many questions that are introductory in nature yet somehow is able to withstand the infantile urge to make snarky, self-important commentary.  Your comment was classy and helpful - bravo!

Comment: @ John : Thanks for suggestion.Will do it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`void` is the return type, so it must go last. The others can be shuffled (see [section 8.4 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) for more details on this), but by convention the access modifier usually goes before most of the other method modifiers, except for annotations which usually go first (again, just by convention).

Comment: [JLS 8.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3): *"If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown:"* Annotation `public` `protected` `private` `abstract` `static` `final` `synchronized` `native` `strictfp`

Answer (score 5):

We can write, we can interchange `static` and `public`

```
static public void main(String args[])

static public void main(String... args)
```

However you cannot reshuffle the return type with any position, for e.g.

```
public void static main(String[] args) // is wrong
```

and also

```
static void public main(String[] args) // is also wrong
```

Comment: Quick java question, can you do `static public void main()` without `String args[]` or `String... args` or is that generally discouraged?

Answer (score 1):

In short, NO, you cant
The method name should be immediately prefixed with the return type of the method.Thats part of the method signature. Having the access specifier first is convention though.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for main needs to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Insert code here
}
```

However, there is no requirement that one method be placed before another method. They can be in whatever order you like. Additionally, Java uses a two-pass mechanism so that even if you use some other method in your "main" method, that method can actually appear later in the file. There is no requirement for forward declaration as in C and C++ because of this multi-pass approach taken by Java.

The modifiers public and static can be shuffled; however, by convention, the access modifier (public, private, protected) is always given first, static and/or final (if applicable) are given next, followed by the return-type.

Comment: You are confused. He is asking about the order of "public" "static" "void" and "main"

Comment: @Kevin, yes, I see. I've now answered both.

Answer (score 1):

You could have easily tried out the various permutations to see what does and does not work.  For one thing, none of them will work if you don't change `main()` to `main(String[] args)`.  Beyond that, `public` and `static` are modifiers that *can* come in any order, but most code style conventions have a prescribed order for them anyway.  The `void` *must* be directly before the method name, since it's the return type, and not a modifier.